# Android buttons with corners and transparency

Tags: android, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a button which is both transparent and has corner radius.Near the corners transparency is more than the rest of the button.How do I prevent it? I'm posting an image of it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Yekz-VsuhmQzdQY0lfZHFONEU/view?usp=sharing`

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="60pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_shapes"
        android:text="@string/get_now"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<resources>
<color name="mediumblue">#990000CD</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color></resources>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners   android:radius="30dp"     />
<solid     android:color="@color/mediumblue"/>
</shape>`
```

Comment: post part of your code...

Comment: Please, edit your question and put the code of one of the buttons so that we can take a look.

Comment: Post your xml code please.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I'm a new to stack exchange.took time to read about how to add code snippet ;)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way of your problem is creating ImageButtons. Do your imagebutton's background image. Then add your image into drawable folder.

Then use it like:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/mybuttonbackimage" />
```

Don't forget use android:background="@null" for transparency of button.

Comment: If I use android:background="@null" then how can i use image background which is  android:background="@drawable/background"

Comment: android:src is your image's source. You must draw your image transparent. Save it as .png file.

Comment: Thanks it Worked! But is there any other solution because I have to create lot of buttons.

Comment: Your welcome. I always use this method for buttons. Can you vote my answer up. I need reputation points :)

Comment: I already voted up.But my vote to be valid I need 15 reputation points. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XML with:

```
<corners android:radius="15dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>
```

Then use this XML like this:

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_name"
        />
```

Comment: I did the same my dear friend.Please read my question completely.